# Is it possible to create a type union that "cross-joins" two or more type unions and how?

Tags: typescript

If, for example, I have two types that contain a union of `ColorName`s and `ColorShade`s, can I generate a `Color` type that effectively contains a union of all possible combinations of the two, e.g.

```ts
type ColorName = 'red' | 'green' | 'blue';
type ColorShade = '100' | '200' | '300';

// ... do some magic here
// ... that creates something akin to:

type Color =
  | 'red100' | 'red200' | 'red300'
  | 'blue100' | 'blue200' // etc, etc...
```

Or, indeed, is there a better way of achieving the end result? (`ColorShade`, or whatever data is on the right, for instance, may not need to be used independently as a `type`.)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you're on typescript 4.1 or later, you can do that with template literal types:

```
type Color = `${ColorName}${ColorShade}`
```

[Playground link](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/C4TwDgpgBAwg9gGzgJwHIEMC20C8UDkyEAJvlAD4EDmREAdmZfgEYICuE+A3ALABQoSLEQoAygAt0xXAQCMABnmMCAJkXL8AZnW8+-QdHhJkUPAAMAJAG8jKDNgC+128glSIDs0A)

[More info on template literal types](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/template-literal-types.html)